# Laravel 5.2 Auto compute fields

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hi can someone please help me on how to auto compute this? I have this
the User will input the value and this will automatically compute the +10% of the fee. total amount will show in id="total fee"

```
    <h1><label id='manager_fee'></label></h1>
    <h1><label id='total_fee'></label></h1>
```

Comment: manager_fee will be a input type ?

Comment: No. that will automatically compute the 10% of the input field

Comment: Can you provide some information with the input fields

Comment: Here is the complete fields.
<input type="text" id="paid_to_you" name="paid_to_you" value="" style="width: 105px;">
<h1><label id='manager_fee'></label></h1>
<h1><label id='total_fee'></label></h1>

WHen user inputs, let's say, 1000, the id 'manager fee' will automatically compute for the 10% of the 'paid to you'

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the input like: `$('#paid_to_you').val();` and then compute it in a function somewhere in your javascript.

When it's done, just add the result to the label like: `$('#manager_fee').text(computedResult);`

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```js
$('#paid_to_you').change(function() {
  var paid_to_you = $(this).val();
  if(paid_to_you > 0){
    paid_to_you = parseInt(paid_to_you);
    var mf = paid_to_you/10;
    $('#manager_fee').text(mf);
    $('#total_fee').text(mf + paid_to_you);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="paid_to_you" name="paid_to_you" value="" style="width: 105px;"> 
<h1><label id='manager_fee'>0</label></h1> 
<h1><label id='total_fee'>0</label></h1>
```